# How can running jre application can use custom provided date and time

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jvm, jvm-hotspot

My application depends upon time, so sometimes I have to move in time to future dates to do some application testing

I have one solution for this.

- Change system date and time and restart the server, but I don't want to do this, this is very time-consuming task, and to change dates in future, affects my system's 365 office and tortoise HG and other applications too.

So basically want I want, I change date and time in server files or somehow tell JVM to point my fake clock, not to actual OS clock.

I know we have `Mokito` to mock the data, but my application is 20 years old without TTD.

I basically want to change the date and time which is `Java` `jre` is pointing to.

Or do we have a way out or `API` to modify the `JRE` `time` and `date`?

I hope you guys understand my problem if still doubt feel free to ask

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This seems to be like a lot of work, just for testing. Can't you do it by creating more unit tests, as everything would rely on dates you choose?

Comment: Had the same issue with a legacy app - we created a DateTimeUtil class where **all** app date/time operations were handled.  The class  has a `long offset` (positive for future dates, negative for past dates) where all relevant operations would include the offset.  And a simple UI for QA folks to change as needed.  This gets real deep real fast when the app is distributed across multiple servers.  Perhaps the newer java.time package could help make this easier.